# Armadillo Matrix Dimensions Initialisation Incorrect

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matrix, 64-bit, armadillo

Briefly, I try to init a matrix as follows:

```
struct MyClass {
  arma::mat _mymat;
};

MyClass::MyClass() : 
_mymat(0,0)
{
}
```

but in the VS2010 debugger, the properties are

```
{n_rows=0 n_cols=14829735428352901220 n_elem=7925840 ... }
```

Later I try to set the dimensions again to 3x3, but then the properties change to

```
{n_rows=3435973836 n_cols=3435973836 n_elem=3435973836 ... }
```

and when I use MyClass._mymat in multiplication the program throws an exception at runtime complaining that the matrix dimensions are not equal.

The platform is VS2010, 64-bit with armadillo 4.200

I have also tried this with previous versions of Armadillo to the same effect.

This error does not occur under Win32 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

TL;DR: ARMA_64BIT_WORD was not defined for the source file I was using, but it was defined for other object files, thus creating an unstable mix of 32-bit and 64-bit word sizes in the Armadillo library.

The simple fix was to add ARMA_64BIT_WORD as a preprocessor macro in the configuration properties for the project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this fix some more? I'm currently running in this through `RcppArmadillo` in an R package and am at a loss for how to fix.